# Compile console android app with SDL2?

Tags: android, opengl-es, sdl, sdl-2

Is there any possiblity to compile console android app with SDL2? I already have libSDL2.so for android and toolchain that is working on android and compile for android (using CppDroid).

I was said that it will be OpenGL ES conflict (as SDL2 uses Open GL behind the scene on Android).

The next source code is said to work on old android, but even fail to launch on modern android:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <GLES/gl.h>

//extern "C" EGLNativeWindowType android_createDisplaySurface(void);
EGLNativeWindowType android_createDisplaySurface(void);

EGLNativeWindowType displayWindow;

int width = 0;
int height = 0;

const EGLint config16bpp[] =
{
    EGL_RED_SIZE, 5,
    EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 6,
    EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 5,
    EGL_NONE
};

GLfloat colors[3][4] =
{
    {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
    {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
    {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}
};

GLfloat vertices[3][3] =
{
    {0.0f, 0.7f, 0.0f},
    {-0.7f, -0.7f, 0.0f},
    {0.7f, -0.7f, 0.0f}
};


void draw_tri()
{
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

    // Draw the triangle (3 vertices)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    EGLint majorVersion, minorVersion;
    EGLContext eglContext = NULL;
    EGLSurface eglSurface;
    EGLConfig eglConfig;
    EGLDisplay eglDisplay = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    int numConfigs;

    // Window surface that covers the entire screen, from libui.
    displayWindow = android_createDisplaySurface();

    eglInitialize(eglDisplay, &majorVersion, &minorVersion);

    printf("GL version: %d.%d\n",majorVersion,minorVersion);

    if (!eglChooseConfig(eglDisplay, config16bpp, &eglConfig, 1, &numConfigs)) {
    printf("eglChooseConfig failed\n");
    if (eglContext == 0) {
        printf("Error code: %d\n", eglGetError());
    }
    }

    eglContext = eglCreateContext(eglDisplay,
    eglConfig,
    EGL_NO_CONTEXT,
    NULL);

    printf("GL context: %p\n", eglContext);

    if (eglContext == 0) {
    printf("Error code: %x\n", eglGetError());
    }

    eglSurface = eglCreateWindowSurface(eglDisplay,
    eglConfig,
    displayWindow,
    NULL);

    printf("GL surface: %p\n", eglSurface);

    if (eglSurface == 0) {
    printf("Error code: %x\n", eglGetError());
    }

    eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay, eglSurface, eglSurface, eglContext);

    eglQuerySurface(eglDisplay, eglSurface, EGL_WIDTH, &width);
    eglQuerySurface(eglDisplay, eglSurface, EGL_HEIGHT, &height);

    printf("w=%d, h=%d\n", width, height);

    while (1) {
    draw_tri();
    eglSwapBuffers(eglDisplay, eglSurface);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://4dc5.com/2013/02/10/compiling-c-console-applications-for-android-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: please read the question carefully. i know how to cross-compile for android and i already have cross-compiled libSDL2.so. The problem is that i can't just include SDL header, compile and link (using toolchain which runs on android and compiles for ARM android) against libSDL2.so because of GLES conflict most likely.

Comment: There are no compile errors in your post.

Comment: the code can be compiled but at runtime SurfaceFlinger will have problems most likely.

Comment: You need to edit your question and clarify what is wrong at all. If something is said not to be true is not good enough for `SO`.

Comment: If it's not clear enough it means you are just not skilled enough in this topic ..

Comment: Neither is anyone else, it would seem.